# Adding Inflated Layout to older inflated layout based on String

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater

I'm inflating multiple of the same view, and also have the ability to delete the views i inflate.

The problem i'm having at the moment is that i want to be able to add an item to an already inflated view that might have been added a few views back.

Image to try and help explain: [image]

The idea is that when a user enters Room 1 into the box at the top left hand side of the page (It currently says Room 2), and then press the + button, it will add it to the already existing Room 1 list just below. Currently it just adds it to the Room 2 which is the most recent view dynamically created.

The problem is that everything is dynamically created and i can't seem to get the values for the views.

Here is the code segment to match the click of the "+":

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            room = roomname.getText().toString();

            if(roomList.isEmpty()) {
                roomList.add(room);

                LayoutInflater layoutInflaterroom = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addRoom = layoutInflaterroom.inflate(R.layout.newroom, null);

                rLayout = (LinearLayout) addRoom.findViewById(R.id.room);

                roomnametitle = (TextView) addRoom.findViewById(R.id.listroomname);
                removeroom = (Button) addRoom.findViewById(R.id.removeRoom);

                removeroom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout) addRoom.getParent()).removeView(addRoom);
                        roomnametitle.getText().toString();
                        roomList.remove(roomnametitle);
                    }
                });

                roomnametitle.setText(room);
                mLayout.addView(addRoom);

                LayoutInflater layoutInflateritem = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflateritem.inflate(R.layout.newitem, null);

                quoteitem = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.partName);
                quoteitemquantity = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                quoteitemrrp = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.rrp);

                new Search().execute();

                buttonRemove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                    }
                });

                rLayout.addView(addView);
                scroll.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN); } });

            } else if (roomList.contains(room)) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflateritem = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflateritem.inflate(R.layout.newitem, null);

                quoteitem = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.partName);
                quoteitemquantity = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                quoteitemrrp = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.rrp);

                new Search().execute();

                buttonRemove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                    }
                });

                rLayout.addView(addView);
                scroll.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN); } });

            } else {
                roomList.add(room);

                LayoutInflater layoutInflaterroom = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addRoom = layoutInflaterroom.inflate(R.layout.newroom, null);

                rLayout = (LinearLayout) addRoom.findViewById(R.id.room);

                roomnametitle = (TextView) addRoom.findViewById(R.id.listroomname);
                removeroom = (Button) addRoom.findViewById(R.id.removeRoom);

                removeroom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout) addRoom.getParent()).removeView(addRoom);
                        roomnametitle.getText().toString();
                        roomList.remove(roomnametitle);
                    }
                });

                roomnametitle.setText(room);
                mLayout.addView(addRoom);

                LayoutInflater layoutInflateritem = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflateritem.inflate(R.layout.newitem, null);

                quoteitem = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.partName);
                quoteitemquantity = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                quoteitemrrp = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.rrp);

                new Search().execute();

                buttonRemove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                    }
                });

                rLayout.addView(addView);
                scroll.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN); } });
            }
```

You'll see in this code i'm trying to delete the corresponding room from roomList if they press "Delete Room", but that doesn't seem to be going to plan either.

I'll take any suggestions/help. I've tried googling but not sure what to specifically google.